# Installing XenServer 6.2 on Proliant DL160G6 freezes during "Installing from base pack"

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, xenserver, hp-smart-array

I'm trying a new install of XenServer 6.2 on an HP Proliant DL160G6 with a HP P410 raid card configured as RAID 5 over 4 drives, with a 256M BBWC.  The install starts off properly, but when it gets to about 56% completion of "Installing from Base Pack", it just completely freezes and stops continuing.  I am unable to switch consoles using Alt-F2, etc.

I've tried rebooting and restarting the install, but to no additional success.

If, however, I reconfigure my HW Raid as Raid 1 or Raid 1+0, the installation is successful, which makes me wonder if this is a compatibility issue with P410 Raid configuration, however, according to the [HCL](http://hcl.xensource.com/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductType=HBA&ProductName=Smart%20Array%20P410i%20RAID), the P410 is listed as compatible.

I've tried running [Inquisitor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inq/) as a stress test on the RAID, and it passes flawlessly in RAID-5 configuration.

How can I further diagnose where the problem lies?  Is there a way to see exactly where/why this is failing?  What would cause it to fail on Raid 5 but not Raid 1?

Comment: It could easily just be a volume size>2TB issue, can you create a 2TB volume off the R5 and try that, then create a 2.TB volumes and try that. Also that's not a supported OS/HW combination by the way.

Comment: Sorry - I should have metionned it, but my RAID 5 is 4x500G drives, so effective logical RAID volume size is roughly 1.5T.  I'm also not sure what you mean by not a supported OS/HW combination.  The HCL seems to indicate that it is?

Comment: Ah ok, well ignore the >2TB thing, we have seen issues with that previously is all. As for support, take a look here; http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/software/citrix/hpcitrixcert.html#DL620

Comment: @Chopper3 I forgot about that; I had seen that page as well, but thought that it might have been an oversight. :)  I don't understand why it installs under RAID 1 or RAID 1+0 without issues though.  I tried installing 6.1 but have run into problems with 6.1 as well "ERROR: :An unrecoverable error has occurred: the decompressor died with signal 2 whilst processing package dom0fs.tar.bz2".  So I wasn't much further ahead there either.

Comment: I agree it's very weird, the OS shouldn't be aware of the array configuration at all. To be honest I detest R5 anyway but that's your choice I guess - don't really know how to move this forward sorry.

Comment: BBWC / FBWC is installed?

Comment: @Striker_84 Yes, I've got a BBWC 256M installed and functional.

Comment: @Chopper3 - Why are you so against R5?

Comment: On 1TB+ drives using R5 inherently introduces unrecoverable errors when rebuilding R5 array simply due to the volume of data that has to be rewritten during a rebuild. It's very well documented and so the vast majority on SF stick to R1/10 and R6, basically the world has outgrown R5 in the same way we did with R3 and R4.

Comment: @EricB. Do you have current firmware installed for the server BIOS, RAID controller and related components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer at: [HP DL320e Gen8, 3TB drives, Windows Server 2012 R2 - HDD full capacity alocation difficulties during installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/578257/hp-dl320e-gen8-3tb-drives-windows-server-2012-r2-hdd-full-capacity-alocation/578262#578262) for general local disk and logical drive guidance. Perhaps there's a 1TB issue that you clear when using RAID 1+0, but not in RAID 5.

But your specific case here appears to be [firmware related](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/294872-upgrading-xenserver-56-sp2-to-xenserver-60-on-proliant-bl460c-g6/). The best course of action is to run the bootable [Service Pack for ProLiant DVD](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features).

Your RAID controller should be at revision **6.40**. There's [plenty in the change log](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884344&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_208de28c836945daaf355281a1%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) that could be the root cause.

Comment: Thanks; I will take a look at that.  I have finished downloading the Service Pack DVD (thanks so much for the link), and will try to install it tomorrow.  I suspected it may be Raid firmware related, but couldn't find anything in the RAID BIOS configurator that indicated the FW version on the card.  I will post updated information once I run the Service Pack.

Comment: I ran the SP and upgraded the P410 firmware and XenServer installs properly now.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricB. Perfect! Glad to see it worked out.